# If HTTP is stateless, how does ASP.NET MVC support sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I get that regular ASP finagles statefullness using viewstate, but MVC doesn't try to perpetuate the bold-faced lie of statefulness. So how is it able to maintain sessions?

Comment: A cookie contains the session ID.

Comment: Ah, so if cookies are disabled, then there is no session. Is it possible to spoof a cookie?

Comment: Yes, you can spoof nearly anything

Comment: @sircodesalot The client can manipulate the cookie as it likes. But if the server does implement sessions correctly, then guessing a valid session id is practically impossible. I don't know how ASP.net does it, but a popular mechanism is generating a random 128 bit value as session ID.

Comment: Maintaining state and session are 2 different things. ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC can handle SessionState. ASP.NET has ViewState for statefull pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default it stores a randomly generated number in a cookie and stores that in memory. If the browser says it doesn't support cookies, asp.net will then instead add the session key in the url, it will show up like http://myurl.com/(S(rpfa4y3c5oe2c555ljanprek))/Controller/Action

Answer (score 1):

It is using a `Session ID` to identify a user, stored in Cookies. Spoofing is possible if your know the victim's ID, and if other security measurements won't interfere (e.g IP based authentication).

Comment: you also can use a fake IP in some circumstances

Comment: Wow, I'm familiar with desktop programming, but I'm fairly new to web development. Sounds like web security is fairly complex. Any resources I can turn to to learn more?

Comment: @sircodesalot: the [OWASP Top 10 Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) is probably you're best starting point

Comment: @sircodesalot actually, not really. It's all about sanitizing input, just like in every server based programming.